# Merge unique rows based on single column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I was just trying to do some herculean task with Oracle.

I have a table containing 3 columns

```
    ColA   ColB   ColC  ColD
  ---------------------------
    123     N     null   1
    100     Y     AAAA   1
    123     Y     XXXX   2
    100     Y     YYYY   2
```

I need to update **ColB** and **ColC** to show following result set.

```
    ColA   ColB  ColC       ColD
  -------------------------------
    123    Y     XXXX         1
    100    Y     AAAA\YYYY    1
    123    Y     XXXX         2
    100    Y     YYYY         2
```

I need to update **ColB** with `Y` if any of the unique records contain `Y` else `N`.

And for **ColC** I want to update the values separated by a `\` where both rows contains a value else just the value.

I have tried to do this with update query but ghosh......... It seems impossible.

Can any one suggest a possible solution or something?

I have been told to use PL/SQL if required. Will that do?

**PS:** I have also seen the other questions that seems similar but havn't got any solution yet.

**EDIT**: We need to update just those rows where **ColD** is `1`.

Comment: you have fewer rows in the result set than in the input. You delete some? How can this be achieved only with updates?

Comment: +1 for the observation. I am really sorry for that. Edited.

Comment: Why are all rows where COLA == 100 _not_ `AAAA\YYYY`? This implies some sort of implicit ordering, which I can't see how you can achieve from the provided data... Do you want only a random row to have both values? Lastly, _why_ do you want to do this at all? Wouldn't it make more sense to leave this normalised or to denormalise it properly so that COLA is unique?

Comment: Ben is right. Why fourth row doesn't have AAAA\YYYY ?

Answer (score 1):

A query to find how colB and colC will look:

```
select 
   colA, 
   case when count(case when colB='Y' then 1 end) > 0 
     then 'Y' 
     else 'N' 
   end as colB,
   LISTAGG(colC, '\') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY colA) AS colC
from your_table
group by colA;
```

From this, you just shoot a MERGE like

```
update your_table  a
using query b
on (a.colA=b.colB and colD=2)
when matched then update 
    a.colB=b.colB, 
    a.colC=b.colC
```

Comment: LISTAGG wont work for me as I am using 10g and I guess its for 11g

Comment: use WM_CONCAT. [http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php)